# How to repeat TK inter callback function

Tags: python, tkinter, priority-queue, tk-toolkit, repeat

I want to repeat a callback function in a Tkinter app, choose_tags. The function takes two priorityqueues and should return/ process one item from each queue per repetition, for instance "NN" from tag_queue and "Katter" from word_queue. The total number of repeats is the same as the len of the lists, 4. I wonder if it's possible to repeat the function by calling it self in the returnstatement, return choose_tags(choice) or if there is a repeat() function that I could use similar to the after() function?

```
import Queue
from Queue import PriorityQueue

from Tkinter import *

import Tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import thread
from time import time, sleep


class Application(Frame):



    def __init__(self, root):
        """ init the frame """
        Frame.__init__(self)


        self.grid()

        self.choice_y_n = tk.StringVar()

        self.q = tk.StringVar()
        self.q2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.q3 = tk.StringVar()


        self.tag_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()
        self.word_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()
        self.word_ls = ["katter", "jagar"]
        self.tag_ls = ["NN","VB"]


        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        choice_Y = tk.Button(self, text = "Yes", command = self.Y)
        choice_Y.grid(row = 14, column = 0, sticky = W)



        choice_N = tk.Button(self, text = "No", command = self.N)
        choice_N.grid(row = 14, column = 1, sticky = W)



        self.w_entry = Entry(self)
        self.w_entry.grid(row = 10, column = 0,  sticky = W)





        self.box_txt = tk.Text(self, width = 65,height = 25, wrap = WORD)
        self.box_txt.grid(row = 15, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W)




    def display_contents(self):

        str_ = self.w_entry.get()
        self.q.set(str_)

        self.word_ls = str_.split()
        self.tag_ls = ["NN","VB","JJ","ADV"]

        return self.q


    def Y(self):
        self.choice_y_n.set("y")
        choice = self.choice_y_n.get()
        self.choose_tags(choice)



    def N(self):
        self.choice_y_n.set("n")
        choice = self.choice_y_n.get()
        self.choose_tags(choice)


    def repeat(self):
        choice = None
        print self.choose_tags(choice)
        root.after(5000,repeat)


    def choose_tags(self, choice):





        for i,j in enumerate(self.word_ls):
            self.word_queue.put((i,j))


        for i,j in enumerate(self.tag_ls):
            self.tag_queue.put((i,j))




        if not self.tag_queue.empty():
            word = list(self.tag_queue.get())


        if not self.word_queue.empty():
            tag = list(self.word_queue.get())

            print tag, word

        #print self.choose_tags(choice)
        #root.after(5000,task)





# Main
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Maltparser1.0_demo")

root.geometry("900x700")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modified after comment from original question**

So since you want to repeat the function for all items in the list I would do something like below. But keep in mind that this would only work if you are using return statement within choose_tags method.

```
processedList = []
For item in ["NN","VB","JJ","ADV"]:
    processeditem = self.choose_tags(item)
    processedList.append(processeditem)
```

Then when you are done, you can manipulate/do what you want to do with the returned items from the each call of the function.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried the code but it goes through the entire list in one run/repeat. I would need it to return NN in the first run,  VB in the second run, after the first run is processed, and so on  from the list ["NN","VB","JJ","ADV"].

Comment: Does my modified answer fit your question better?

Comment: I've edited the code in the post and commented out the after() in the end the callback function choose_tags which is supposed to be called from repeat but it doesn't work. I want it to return one item from each list self.tag_ls and self.word_ls for each repeat

Answer (score 0):

The `after()` method doesn't automatically reschedule things for you; it's one-shot. To make it repeat, call `after()` again inside the callback that it runs. There are cases to be made for putting the reschedule first or last inside the callback; both work, but I find it is usually better to put it last so that the reschedule only happens if everything else is successful. (A rescheduled error is *not* nice!)

Comment: I've edited the code in the post and commented out the after() in the end the callback function choose_tags which is supposed to be called from repeat but it doesn't work. I want it to return one item from each list self.tag_ls and self.word_ls for each repeat